# How to prove that "For AR(p), the stationary and ergodic condition is all the roots of characteric equation lie outside the complex unit circle"

Tags: time-series, econometrics

**I have seen several textbooks about TSA, all just provided the answer, without proof, I tried by myself, but failed**

Comment: Try Brockwell/Davis, https://www.springer.com/de/book/9780387974293.